# kernel: synchronizing deletion of shared field of task_struct

Tags: linux-kernel, process

I would like to add a pointer (to an object) to task_struct that is shared between all threads in the group. After the object has been deleted by 1 thread, how could I ensure that another thread will not attempt to dereference the invalid pointer.

Could I add an atomic variable reference field to task_struct, and then update them in sync across all threads of a process (hold a global spinlock while traversing task_structs)?

Or implementing a kernel thread that manages the objects and their reference counts. Seems like this problem must have been solved by other shared entities like virtual memory and file handles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by defining you own datastructure:
    struct my_task_data {
        void *real_data;
    }

The task_struct must be enhanced:
    struct task_struct {
         ....
         struct my_task_data *mtd;
    };

In the clone() call you need to handle the mdt member of the task_struct.
real_data points to whatever you want. Doing it this way means you have one pointer from each task_struct to a shared object (mtd) which is always valid and can be dereferenced at any time. This shared object contains a pointer to your actual data item. When you want to access the item do:

```
 data = current()->mtd->real_data;
```

if data is NULL another thread has deleted it, otherwise it can be used.

**Locking issues are not shown in this example**.

Of course you need to protect access to real_data by some locking mechanism, like a mutex or semaphore in the my_task_data structure and use it while manipulating my_task_data.